# If $\tan x=\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}$ where a,b are positive real numbers and x is in 1st quadrant then find the value of $\sin x\sec^7x+\cos x\csc^7x$

Tags: trigonometry

The answer is $\frac{(a+b)^3(a^4+b^4)}{(ab)^{\frac{7}{2}}}$. I just want to now how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3):

you say $$\tan t = \sqrt{a/b}, 0 < t < \pi/2 \to y = \sin t = \sqrt{\frac a{a+b}}, x = \cos t = \sqrt{\frac b{a+b}}$$

then $$\begin{align}\sin t \sec^7 t + \cos t \csc ^7 t &= \frac y{x^7} + \frac x{y^7} \\
&= \frac{x^8+y^8}{(xy)^7} \\
&= \frac{(a+b)^3(a^4+b^4)}{(ab)^{7/2}}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

We very well know that $$\color {blue}{\sec^2 x-\tan^2 x=1}$$ $$\implies  \sec^2 x=1+\tan^2 x=1+\left(\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\right)^2=1+\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a+b}{b}$$ $$\implies \sec x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{b}}$$ But x lies in the first quadrant i.e. $\color{blue}{0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}}$ hence $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\csc x$ & $\sec x$ all have positive values in the I-quadrant, thus we have $$\color {blue}{ \sec x= \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{b}}}$$ $$\implies \cos x=\frac{1}{\sec x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{b}}}=\sqrt{\frac{b}{a+b}}$$  $$\implies \sin x=\frac{\tan x}{\sec x}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}}{\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{b}}}=\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}$$ $$\implies \csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}=\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a}}$$ 
 Now substituting the above values, we have $$\sin x\sec^7 x+\cos x\csc^7 x=\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{b}}\right)^7+\sqrt{\frac{b}{a+b}}\left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a}}\right)^7 $$ $$=\frac{(a+b)^3}{b^3} \sqrt{\frac{a}{a+b}}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{b}}+\frac{(a+b)^3}{a^3}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a+b}}\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a}}$$ $$=\frac{(a+b)^3}{b^3}\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}+\frac{(a+b)^3}{a^3}\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}} $$ $$=(a+b)^3\left[\frac{a^{\frac{1}{2}}}{b^{\frac{7}{2}}}+\frac{b^{\frac{1}{2}}}{a^{\frac{7}{2}}}\right]$$ $$=(a+b)^3\left[\frac{a^4+b^4}{a^{\frac{7}{2}}b^{\frac{7}{2}}}\right]$$$$=\color{purple}{\frac{(a+b)^3(a^4+b^4)}{(ab)^{\frac{7}{2}}}}$$